# android-studio login button doesn't change activity

Tags: android-studio

I am creating an android studio simple demo. I am doing the login. But when press the submit button it doesn't change the activity.
Main.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /* Get button Text1 Text2 */
        final EditText  edUsername  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        final EditText  edPassword  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        Button btnValidate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                String uname  = edUsername.getText().toString();
                String pass = edPassword.getText().toString();
                if(uname.equals("user") && pass.equals("12345"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,Success.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username",edUsername.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Invalid Usename password pair.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Success.java

```
public class Success extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Welcome ,"+getIntent().getExtras().getString("username"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Success"
            android:label="AndroidTest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidTest"
            android:label="AndroidTest" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What is wrong? Just edited it with Mainfest file content. Again it doesn't changes the activity when submit button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the Success Activity in your Manifest file? similar to the code below? 
   `<activity
        android:name=".Success"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />`

Hope this helps!

Comment: either main is missing in mainfest file. should I add it too?

Comment: Do you mean you are running AndroidTest then it goes to Main then to Success? Yes please try. Do you see any red marks or errors in your LogCat?

Comment: You can also try to debug the code if it's going to the Success Activity or not... Try placing Breakpoints inside btnValidate.setOnClickListener and the Success Activity's onCreate methods.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your line for starting activity it should be like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Success.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username",edUsername.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.class,Success.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username",edUsername.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

in `new intent(_,_)` you need to pass the context first. that can be done by either using `this`,`getActivity()`,`getApplicationContext()`.Hope this is not too late